# If one app sends out multiple notifications, are all of the notification ID's the same?

Tags: android, notifications

For example, lets say if the messaging app sends out 3 notifications of text messages, would the notifications IDs be the same? If not, are there any similarities between said notifications so I can perform an action like say, silence the phone?

Comment: you want to send three different notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary that the notifications will come from same ID.....so if you want to disable the notifications check the app settings tab......if no luck there, you can visit the app support section on app website.....

Comment: I was wanting to do it programmatically